# Error in loading physi.js and ammo.js

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, physijs

I'm trying to develop a project with physijs. I have encountered this type of error (from mozilla firefox console):

- NetworkError: Failed to load worker script at "js/libs/ammo.js"

[image: error_log]

I'm trying to fix it but with no results. This is my code snippet on physijs setup:

```
<script src="build/three.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/physi.js"></script>
<script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="js/Detector.js"></script>

<script>

    'use strict';

    Physijs.scripts.worker = 'js/libs/physijs_worker.js';
    Physijs.scripts.ammo = 'js/libs/ammo.js';
```

All javascript files are in js directory, except for Three.js building files (that are in build directory). I have no idea what's wrong in my code, I create only lights, ground (compoud shapes following Physijs rules) and a bag (that I want to apply a cone-twist constaint but for previous reasons doesn't work).

I add even the code that I use to initialize the scene (if in case there is something wrong):

```
function createScene() {

            var container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

            //stats = new Stats();
            //container.appendChild( stats.dom );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
            camera.position.x = 0;
            camera.position.z = 17;
            camera.position.y = 12;

            //scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene = new Physijs.Scene;
            scene.setGravity(new THREE.Vector3( 0, -10, 0 ));


            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;
            //renderer.gammaInput = true;
            //renderer.gammaOutput = true;
            renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
            //renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
            //renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ReinhardToneMapping;
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


            var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.target.set( 0, 0, 0 );
            controls.noPan = true;  //disable panning of orbit control
            controls.noKeys = true; //disable arrow keys of orbit control
            controls.update();

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            window.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );
            window.addEventListener( 'keyup', onKeyUp, false );

        }
```

How can I fix this problem and import correctly Physi.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED** I used a local web server ([Three.js's reference](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally))and changed this:

```
Physijs.scripts.worker = 'js/libs/physijs_worker.js';
Physijs.scripts.ammo = 'ammo.js';
```